# I can't keep my server running once I close terminal or my ssh session

Tags: node.js, terminal, npm, server, digital-ocean

I have never set up a server before but since Parse announced that they are closing down I thought I might give it a shot. I have followed along with [this tutorial](http://julienrenaux.fr/2016/01/29/complete-parse-server-migration-guide/#disqus_thread) and have managed to migrate my Parse database across to digital ocean.

When I call `npm run start` everything works fine. I can query for data and create new objects all from my iOS app. But there is just one problem. How do I keep the server up and running even when terminal is not running from my Mac.

When I call `npm run start` this is what gets logged in terminal:

```
> parse-server-example@1.0.0 start /var/www/parse
> node index.js

[TypeError: Cannot read property 'Kerberos' of undefined]
DATABASE_URI not specified, falling back to localhost.
parse-server-example running on port 1337.
```

I know that this is probably a noob question and yes my knowledge is quite limited, so if you could help me then that would be great!

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Okay so I have just found the answer after posting a question on the Digital Ocean question page, instead of running `npm run start` I should have been doing `nohup npm start &`

Answer (score 5):

1. use screen to create a new session https://tournasdimitrios1.wordpress.com/2010/11/04/linux-the-screen-command-a-must-for-ssh/
2. start your server
3. detach session
4. return to running session when needed

Comment: thanks. Is there any way that I can keep the server running even when my the computer that I am using terminal on to start the server is without power.

Comment: After detaching the session you can turn off your computer - the server will still work. Next time you can return to session running in backgroung using command screen -r

Comment: what is involved in detaching the session, does closing terminal detach the session?

Comment: Everything is in article from the link: 1. Start new screen session using command screen. 2. In the new session start the server. 3. Detach session, you have two options 1.Ctrl+a d Detach but keep shell window open, 2. Ctrl+a D (Shift-d) Power detach and logout

Comment: I have tried both detach methods, and as soon as I power down my computer, I can no longer receive data from the server

Comment: hm, I didn't use Parse but it works great when I start remote django web-server over SSH...

Answer (score 1):

+1 to Lev for his answer, I don't have enough reputation to upvote his answer.

Another option is tmux, like screen, you create a session then start your app and detach when done and your app will continue to run.

Answer (score 0):

I see this document can help you. https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever. I tried in window. It is OK.

Those are my comment

*** Run background code with schedule

- Linux: nohup file-nodejs.js &
- Window:

  - Install forever:  npm install forever -g
  - Start/Stop : forever start file-nodejs.js | forever stop file-nodejs.js (restartall | restart | stopall)
  - Reference : https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever